# Facebook Applications

Tags: facebook

I just wanted to know if there is a way to host a facebook application in facebook's servers and not elsewhere. is facebook providing hoting for applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hosting provided by facebook for facebook applications. There are currently two types of facebook applications: iFrame and FBML. iFrame apps can be coded using the sdk's in your language of choice and are a bit more open as far as javascript, database and other functionality. The FBML apps must be written using facebook's markup language FBML, FBJS and FQL for queries. This route is a bit more limited as you can only use the FB markup, js and query languages. Whichever one of these paths you choose you will need to host your code yourself.

You should check this out:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Facebook recently updated these docs with the release of the GraphAPI, they are much better than before. Good place to get started.